# Microsoft Word not Displaying The Entire Document?

Tags: microsoft-word

When I use Word it does not display the entire size of 8.5 x 11 or any size paper: It only displays 7 x 9 of 8.5 x 11. How can I fix this?

Another problem I have is, it automatically saves a back-up in the same folder I save the original document. How can I fix this? EX: I save the document as "Doc1", above this, it will say "Backup of Doc1"

Comment: Welcome to the site! The site is based on one question per - um - Question, so you should really edit this and move your second request out to a new question... See the FAQ (linked at the top right) for more advice on writing effective questions.

Comment: Are you just zoomed in?

Comment: For the second problem (i think) just switch of the viewing hidden files & folders.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what version of Word (or OS) you're using but with mine there's a "Print Layout" option on the View menu which shows me the entire page right to the edge of the paper when it's selected.

For your second question, you can change a setting that controls where Word stores the default back-ups it creates. In my version this is located on the "File Locations" tab of the dialog that appears when the "Options..." Tool menu item is selected. It's the one labeled "AutoRecover files".

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with the entire page not showing up. Then I found this in Word help and it took care of it: "If your document is in Print Layout view and the top and bottom margins appear to be cut off, the option for hiding margins has been switched on. Here's how to switch it off:

1.Point to the top or bottom of a page until the pointer becomes a double-pointed arrow, and then double-click."